# How to make whole row of DataGrid(not GridView) clickable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagrid

I was searching for a way on how to select a whole row in **DataGrid** but I saw only a `GridView`code. Here is the sample code:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
    e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
    e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
    e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
  End If
End Sub
```

so for it to work on my DataGrid, I had some changes on my code and made it like this:

```
Private Sub DataGrid_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.ItemCreated
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Item.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        e.Item.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.DataGrid, "Select$" & e.Item.ItemIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

But it seems that it is not firing,(i think there is a problem on the `onclick`part) but it is highlighting though. What i would like to do is place a `CommandName = Select` on the `onclick` in javascript, but how?

EDIT: This in now my new code.

```
Private Sub DataGrid_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.ItemCreated

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Item.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        Dim button As LinkButton
        button = DirectCast(e.Item.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)
        Dim js As String = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(button, "")
        e.Item.Attributes("onclick") = js
    End If
End Sub
```

But the only thing has changed (on what i observed) is that it just postbacks.

Comment: Why don't you use a `GridView` in the first place? The `DataGrid` is very old and redundant. There's no advantage over a `GridView`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I have many codes already in this DataGrid. So i need to use this all the way. If i change my grid into GridView, I will have so many revisions :(

Comment: Then have al look at this approach here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/aspnet-cookbook/0596003781/ch01s17.html

Comment: The link you suggested used static values for the buttons. But my datagrid 's value varies.

Comment: What means _static values_? If i see it correctly he just presumes that the linkbutton in the first column. He uses `AutoGenerateColumns=false` and `BoundFields`, but the datasource is dynamic.

Comment: I already placed the code but its not working. But the progress is that the page postbacks. So if i click my button column, the page just refreshes, no more other than that.

Comment: it's important that the `LinkButton` has `CommandName="Select"`. That should trigger the [`SelectedIndexChanged`-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i checked my `ButtonColumn` and it has a `CommandName="Select"`. I also traced(placed a red marker) on my selectedindexchanged event but it does not debug there.

Comment: but you are databinding your `DataGrid` only if `Not Page.IsPostBack`?

Comment: yes @TimSchmelter, according to my Page_Load

Comment: Is at least  the `DataGrid.ItemCommand` event triggered?

Comment: it does not :( and also btw, my itemcommand is blank. I only have codes in ItemCreated, SelectedIndexChanged and ItemDataBound. I also edited my question and updated my current code, I might have missed something important.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you handle the `DataGrid.ItemCommand` event:

```
Private Sub DataGrid_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.ItemCommand
    Me.DataGrid.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
End Sub
```

Use `DataGrid.ItemDataBound` instead of `DataGrid.ItemCreated` :

```
    Private Sub DataGrid_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Item.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Item.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        'e.Item.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.DataGrid, "Select$" & e.Item.ItemIndex)

        Dim button As LinkButton
        button = DirectCast(e.Item.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)
        'Dim js As String = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.DataGrid, "Select$" & e.Item.ItemIndex)
        Dim js As String = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(button, "")

        e.Item.Attributes("onclick") = js
    End If
End Sub
```

Then I added the following to the markup of the DataGrid, just to highlight the selection:

```
<SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Red" />
```

Comment: The code you provided only works if I press the "Select" button. But what i have to do is that the WHOLE row should be clickable, not the Select Button only, because I will also hide that one.

Comment: Ok, didn't realise you needed the whole row to be clickable. I will edit the answer

Comment: Edited a while ago, hope that helps

Comment: @Dale, could you post your code please? I have this working in Chrome, FF, Opera, IE and Edge

Comment: Are you referring to the whole row clickable? not the `select` button only?

Comment: @Dale yes, the whole row is clickable